# string manipulations using R

Tags: regex, r

I am working with a string vector.Each element in the vector is in the format "MMYYPub". I want to switch the place of "MM" and "YY" in the string, from "MMYYPub" to "YYMMPub" . Is this feasible in R.
Example :

```
 vec(1)
'0100pub'
 vec(2)
'0200pub'
```

Where the first two digits are month, and the following digits are year. There 10 years data in total from 1994 to 2013.

Comment: Could you provide some example data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read up on regular expressions.  Here is one way:

```
R> val <- "0405pub"
R> gsub("(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(.*)", "\\2\\1\\3", val)
[1] "0504pub"
R>
```

We use the fact that

- `\d` denotes a digit (but need to escape the backslash)
- `(...)` groups arguments, so here we matches one (two digits), two (also two digits) and three (remainder)
- we then "simply" create the replacement string as "two before one followed by three"

There are other ways to do it, this will accomplish given the pattern you described.

*Edit:* Here is a shorter variant using `\\d{2}` to request two digits:

```
R> gsub("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\2\\1", val)
[1] "0504pub"
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning how to group in regular expressions. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

It might also be useful to know about the `yearmon` class to represent monthly data. The `yearmon` object can then printed in a `format` of choice.

```
library(zoo)
ym <- as.yearmon("0414pub", format = "%m%ypub")
ym
# [1] "apr 2014"

format(ym, "%y%mpub")
# [1] "1404pub"
```

Answer (score 4):

One way would be using ([`gsub`](http://rfunction.com/archives/2354)) to replace all occurrences in the vector.

```
> vec <- c('0100pub', '0200pub')
> gsub('([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '\\2\\1', vec)
[1] "0001pub" "0002pub"
```

Comment: I think your code also works. Just Dirk's answer involves less typing by using \\d

Comment: The two answers are really equivalent. `[0-9]` is another way of saying `\d`, the `{2}` then requests precisely two of those.

Comment: Actually `\d` checks all Unicode digits, while `[0-9]` is limited to these 10 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need regex for this, if you just want to swap the characters around.  `substring` and `paste` work just as well in this case:

```
> f <- function(x) paste0(substring(x,3,4), substring(x,1,2), substring(x,5))
> x
[1] "0103pub" "0204pub"
> f(x)
[1] "0301pub" "0402pub"
```

Comment: Same reason why you should not use string operations to parse dates (unless your name is Simon U.): less structure, less control, more errors.  Been there, done that.